# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Tags: python, visualization, lda

pyLDAvis library `prepare` method has crashed while using pandas library inside.

Here is the code:

```
    def load_R_model(filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as j:
            data_input = json.load(j)
        data = {'topic_term_dists': data_input['phi'],
                'doc_topic_dists': data_input['theta'],
                'doc_lengths': data_input['doc.length'],
                'vocab': data_input['vocab'],
                'term_frequency': data_input['term.frequency']}
        return data

    movies_model_data = load_R_model('movie_reviews_input.json')
    print('Topic-Term shape:%s' %str(np.array(movies_model_data['topic_term_dists']).shape))
    print('Doc-Topic shape: %s' %str(np.array(movies_model_data['doc_topic_dists']).shape))

    movies_vis_data =         pyLDAvis.prepare(np.array(movies_model_data['topic_term_dists']),
                               np.array(movies_model_data['doc_topic_dists']),
                               np.array(movies_model_data['doc_lengths']),
                               np.array(movies_model_data['vocab']),
                               np.array(movies_model_data['term_frequency']))
```

Error:

> ... line 283, in prepare
>      topic_proportion=>(topic_freq/topic_freq.sum()).sort_values(ascending=False) 
>   ...
>
> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Why pandas has no attribute as `sort_values` although I updated most recent version?

Comment: Are you sure the version has been updated? what does `pd.__version__` show?

Comment: Good point. I've just checked it says 0.13.1. However I did `sudo pip install -U pandas`

Comment: well you need to sort that out first, you can use `.sort` instead if you have an older version

Comment: I should use 0.17.1 in order to use `prepare` method . However I can not upgrade it, saying package pandas successfully upgraded while version is still 0.13.1

Answer (score 4):

As per the documentation. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

'sort_values' is new in version 0.17.0.
So, please update pandas version.

How to check pandas version:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
```

How to update pandas.

using conda: `conda update pandas`

using pip: `pip install pandas -U`

Answer (score 3):

I have got the same error recently. It's because of [pandas.DataFrame.sortlevel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sortlevel.html) is deprecated since pandas version 0.20.0. Use  [DataFrame.sort_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_index) instead. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Latest Version of Pandas has **.sort_values()**

`import pandas as pd`

`pd.sort_values()`

Can Be Used

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error on a problem 'sort_values' has been Deprecated since version 0.20.0. Use DataFrame.sort_index()

Answer (score 0):

The pandas package cancelled the sort method in the 0.23.4 version. The old version of the Series and DataFrame objects also contain this function. The new version recommends the use of the sort_index and sort_values ​​functions

use
sort_values()
OR
sort_index()

Answer (score 0):

```
df.sort_values(by='col1', ascending=False)
```

or

```
df.sort_values(by='col1', ascending=True)
```

`co1` is column with the values you want to sort.